# Connecting to Team Foundation Service with command line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to connect to tfs in the cloud with the command line but i don't manage to authenticate.

I'm using "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"

I'm using the alternate credentials described in https://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2012/aug-27/

Like this :

```
tf workspaces 
   /computer:* 
   /format:brief 
   /collection:https://*****.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /login:****,****
```

But I get ... `TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://*****.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2012 RTM only or with CU updates?

Comment: I have the latest updates

Comment: Have you been able to connect to the Team Foundation Service instance when opening Visual Studio and connecting to it in Team Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this with my online tfs  account able to reproduce the error you got.

**Steps**

1. I tried the command I was connecting fine and got the workspace info.
2. I Closed all browsers VS and the clear all browser caches.
3. Open VS and connect through team explorer and provide wrong credentials
4. Close VS and try the command got the error TF30063
5. Open VS and connected to visualstudio.com tfs with correct credentials and close VS
6. Tried the command again and it works
7. Tried command with incorrect credentials still it works :)

**Conclusion**

I think the credentials are cached what ever credential we supply in the command line is ignored for team foundation service.

Further search took me to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a688cccd-9b47-4e7c-9668-cb113c21f182/problems-with-tfs-servicetfsvisualstudiocom) and I think it explains the same situation

**For on premises TFS**

The credentials provided in tf workspaces /login: 100% in effect