# Access Denied trying connect to TFS Server

Tags: macos, azure, tfs, azure-repos

I am using MAC OS Catalina. I have a project repos in Azure. Initially when I was using Mojave I was able to connect to Azure TFS through TEE-CLC following this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019

Now in Catalina, everytime I am trying to connect using the command

```
export TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=1
tf workspace -new MyWorkspace -collection:https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization
```

I am getting an Error:

```
Access denied connecting to TFS server https://projectorca.visualstudio.com/ (authenticating as PersonalAccessToken)
```

It did not asked for any username or PAT password to enter. Just the message. Did anyone find this issue in mac Catalina. Need some guidance

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `/login` parameter to tf workspace command.

```
tf workspace login:username,[password] -new MyWorkspace -collection:https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization
```

For details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspaces-command?view=tfs-2018).

After that, if you get TF30063 error, you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667813/connecting-to-team-foundation-service-with-command-line) to solve it

Comment: Result is same. No matter what I do I get this error

```
Access denied connecting to TFS server https://visual.<domain>.com/ (authenticating as PersonalAccessToken)
```

Comment: You can check whether the PAT has expired and has the corresponding access. You can try to use a new PAT with full access scope.

Comment: I have created a new PAT only with full scope but not working